# How to a save a image into a folder on linux from windows

Tags: php, linux, database, image-uploading

So i want to save an image from windows to my linux folder im using LAMP i create a php for save images into a folder on windows works perfectly but when i upload the file to linux, and i tested dont work this is the php im using the redbean framework.

The server I did it with lamp and I use google chrome to access it when I select the image to insert it saves the route but it does not save the image in the folder of the server that is in linux

Other thing i open the server via google chrome and it's work the php save the text the img url but dont save the image into the linux folder.

CODE:

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
$b=R::dispense('blog');
$fileName=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];

$file=$_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

if (is_uploaded_file($file))
{
        echo $fileName;
        $destino="/var/www/html/blog/imgsubidas/".$fileName;
                move_uploaded_file($file,$destino);
$b->titulo=$_POST["titulo"];
$b->imagen=$destino;
$b->contenido=$_POST["content"];
$b->fecha=date("d/m/Y");
        R::store($b);

        header('location:dashboard.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Typo. You forgot the `/` at the start of the path.

Comment: what do u mean by linux from windows???

Comment: @MohitKumar the server I did it with lamp and I use google chrome to access it when I select the image to insert it saves the route but it does not save the image in the folder of the server that is in linux

Comment: the only image is not moving into folder , but inserted full path in database.

Comment: @MohitKumar yes inserts the path but no the images and i need to move the file into the folder to call it from the database

Comment: check ur path is correct or not??  & let me know

Comment: @MohitKumar yes the path is correct

Comment: which is ur image folder to store in root directory ,

Comment: the folder is imgsubidas

Comment: then use $destino="imgsubidas/".$fileName; & let me know  what happens???

Comment: @MohitKumar Still the same they only changes the path at imgsubidas\goku.png